How to <include> a local model into GZ-Sim Harmonic from a world.sdf?
I am trying to <include> local models into my Gazebo Harmonic environment using the world.sdf file. Using the <include><uri>model://[model-name]</uri></include> method. Which results in these errors:
[ruby $(which gz) sim-2] [Err] [Server.cc:204] Error Code 14: [/sdf/world[@name="test_world"]/include[0]/uri:/home/rosdev/ros2_ws/install/bffp_gazebo/share/bffp_gazebo/resources/world.sdf:L47]: Msg: Unable to find uri[model://conveyor_belt]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-2] [Err] [Server.cc:204] Error Code 14: [/sdf/world[@name="test_world"]/include[1]/uri:/home/rosdev/ros2_ws/install/bffp_gazebo/share/bffp_gazebo/resources/world.sdf:L51]: Msg: Unable to find uri[model://ir_sensor]

How does one add model paths properly to the gz-sim library? Similar methods used to work for Gazebo11 (Classic), but I cannot find any documentation on how to do this for Gazebo Harmonic.
I have found a thread which asked a similar question but this "solution" did not work for me.
Below are the architecture and important files from my package.
The world.sdf:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.8">
  <world name="test_world">
    <physics name="1ms" type="ignored">
      <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>1.0</real_time_factor>
    </physics>
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-physics-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Physics">
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-user-commands-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::UserCommands">
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-scene-broadcaster-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::SceneBroadcaster">
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-sensors-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Sensors">
      <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
    </plugin>

    <light type="directional" name="sun">
      <cast_shadows>true</cast_shadows>
      <pose>0 0 10 0 0 0</pose>
      <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
      <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
      <attenuation>
          <range>1000</range>
          <constant>0.9</constant>
          <linear>0.01</linear>
          <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
      </attenuation>
      <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
    </light>

    <include>
      <uri>model://conveyor_belt</uri>
      <pose>-0.8 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>

    <include>
      <uri>model://ir_sensor</uri>
      <pose>-0.25 -1.2 0.15 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>
  </world>
</sdf>


The launch file gz_world.launch.py:
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, AppendEnvironmentVariable
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
from launch.substitutions import PathJoinSubstitution

def generate_launch_description():

    resource_path = get_package_share_directory("bffp_gazebo") + "/resources"
    world = resource_path + "/world.sdf" 
    set_gazebo_model_path_env = AppendEnvironmentVariable("GZ_SIM_SYSTEM_PLUGIN_PATH*", resource_path)
    start_gazebo_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            PathJoinSubstitution([
                FindPackageShare("ros_gz_sim"),
                'launch',
                'gz_sim.launch.py'
            ])
        ),
        launch_arguments=[('gz_args', [' -r -v 4 ', world])])
    

    bridge = get_package_share_directory("bffp_gazebo") + "/config/ros_gz_bridge.yaml" 
    start_gazebo_ros_bridge_cmd = Node(
        package='ros_gz_bridge',
        executable='parameter_bridge',
        parameters=[
            {'config_file': bridge }
        ],
        arguments=['/clock@rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock[gz.msgs.Clock'],
        output='screen'
    )  
    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            set_gazebo_model_path_env,
            start_gazebo_ros_bridge_cmd,
            start_gazebo_cmd,
        ]
    )

And the package is set up like this:
bffp_gazebo
|- config
|  |- ros_gz_bridge.yaml
|- launch
|  |- gz_world.launch.py
|- resources
|  |- conveyor_belt
|  |  |- meshes/conveyor.dae
|  |  |- model.config
|  |  |- model.sdf
|  |- ir_sensor
|  |  |- model.config
|  |  |- model.sdf
|  |- world.sdf
|- CMakeLists.txt
|- package.xml

The model names inside the model.sdf and model.config are identical to the directory name they are in.

There are two ways to do this:

Add the directory that contains your model to the GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH environment variable. In your case, it would be

    set_gazebo_model_path_env = AppendEnvironmentVariable("GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH", resource_path)


Use colcon hooks to automatically add the path to GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH. Here is an example. Assuming you've installed your models to <package prefix>/share/resources, your .dsv.in file would be

prepend-non-duplicate;GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH;@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/share/@PROJECT_NAME@/resources


Thanks, 1. worked like a charm.
For option 2. I had to make a minor change to the dsv.in:
prepend-non-duplicate;GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH;@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/share/@PROJECT_NAME@/resources

Thanks, I've updated my answer. I believe it can also be set to prepend-non-duplicate;GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH;share/@PROJECT_NAME@/resources, but I haven't verified.
